# compare sql between two server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I'm new to sql, can anyone help me out

I have two server names(connect-> database engine-> server Name)

server name X has database a
server name y has database b

how to compare views in database a in server x and database b in sever y

Both Actually having same views, I'm trying to find any Alter/changes in views

Thanks

Comment: Is this only a Microsoft SQL Server question? If so, remove the mysql tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to use the Schema Compare feature of [SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt). This allows one to compare database schema and apply changes as desired.

Another method is generate database scripts for each database using SSMS or Powershell and then use a file diff tool to identify differences.

Comment: right click on database name->tasks->generate scripts and did for two databases, how to compare them -@danguzman

Comment: Any folder/file diff tool will do. I use [Beyond Compare](https://www.scootersoftware.com/) but there are free ones too. Bingle "free file compare tool".